# Javascript to record multiple selections from a list box will only separate with commas

Tags: javascript, concatenation, multi-select

I am using a database platform and I have a multi-select listbox thanks to some javascript. The only issue is I need these items separated by ";" instead of ",". I have that as the separating character in the code and otherwise this code works as intended (it stores multiple selections).

Here is the code:

```
var v_state = "[@field:Reason_for_Cancelltaion]" ;
var o_state = document.getElementById("EditRecordReason_for_Cancelltaion") ;
o_state.multiple = true ;

function f_listbox() {
  if ( v_state.indexOf(";") > 0 ) {
    for (var i=0 ; i < o_state.options.length; i++ ) {
      if(o_state[i].value == v_state) {
        o_state.remove(i);
        break ;
      }
    }
    var o_st = v_state.split("; ");
    for (var j=0 ; j < o_st.length; j++) {
      for (var i=0 ; i < o_state.options.length; i++ ) {
        if(o_st[j]== o_state.options[i].value){
          o_state.options[i].selected = true ;
          break ;
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
window.onload = f_listbox ;
```

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Edit: I should have explained a bit better, the original code has "," where the two ";" exist, I thought simply swapping the character would be enough.

This is code designed to be used with Caspio and the documentation can be found [here](http://forums.caspio.com/index.php/topic/4315-js-multiselect-listbox-in-update-datapage/).

Comment: That makes no sense at all. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `v_state` is a string, so it is unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: It seems you're just trying to replace comma's with semi-colons? Why not just use the `string.replace` function?

Answer (score 0):

If the result is an array named 'result' join it with whatever chars you want with:

```
result.join(';')
```

If the result is a string named 'result' change the characters specified with:

```
result.replace(', ',';')
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to Javascript, where in the above code would I need to add those elements? The current script simply records the result (separated by commas at the moment) into the field "Reason_for_Cancellation" in my database.